# Is there any point in using an 'enum' type instead of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Coming from a background in statically typed languages, the main benefit I get from enums is compile time error catching.

I'm writing a little program in Javascript, and I find myself wanting something like an enum, perhaps like this:

```
var Fruit = {
   BANANA: "BANANA",
   APPLE: "APPLE",
   PEAR: "PEAR"
};
```

But I see no advantage to this.  I might as well just use strings everywhere this 'enum' is required.

Should I just be using strings in javascript in place of enum types in other languages?

Comment: You might be interested in: http://stijndewitt.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/. Enums can be useful!

Comment: You can do things like `if (input in Fruit)` without having to write out the list of all fruits every time.

Comment: magic strings are bad

Comment: I'm not completely convinced, but you guys have pointed out a few advantages that slipped my mind.  Firstly, putting the enum 'types' into an object like I did above documents 'in-code' the range of values.  Second, using an IDE or text editor with some auto-complete feature could help.  Third, the 'if (input in Fruit)' is a nice short way to check if a variable is part of an 'enum'.

Answer (score 3):

It is good way to extract common things like magic numbers/strings or similar. Imagine that you have `BANANA` all over the place then for some reason you need to change `BANANA` to `SOMETHING_ELSE`, without approach you are using in question you need to make a change in every single place.

```
var foo = {
  bar: "baz"
}
```

So using `foo.bar` instead of hardcoded string `"baz"` all over the place, can save your time and possible bugs when it comes to changing `"baz"` to something else.

Comment: This argument doesn't make much sense in the light of enums. Instead of changing `"BANANA"` to `"SOMETHING_ELSE"` everywhere, we'd have to change `Fruit.BANANA` to `Fruit.SOMETHING_ELSE` everywhere?

Comment: I agree, and in a strongly typed language this benefits me by protecting me from typos and assigning wrong types.  But in a language like java, I get neither of those two things.  However, I do recognize that extracting magic numbers and strings aids in documentation.

Comment: @Bergi You're confusing the `variable name` (the name of the variable) with the `variable content` (whats inside the variable). The `BANANA` & `SOMETHING_ELSE` would be the content inside the variable, just like `"baz"` is inside `foo.bar`

Comment: @SebastianNorr OP was asking about string enums, where the property name usually equals the string content (or the other way round). If the value means something else than the name, you've done something wrong - and having to change one without having to change the other is a rare occurence.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage to having an enum is that it's kind of a 'centralized place' where you will be able to see all possible values. Intuitively this sounds like a good thing to have instead of using numerous string all over the code.

Also, as Barmar said in the comment

> You can do things like if (input in Fruit) without having to write out the list of all fruits every time

you'll be able to have all possible values by using a single reference to your enum, instead of writing them again and again. Like `if (input in Fruit)`;

So having enum makes sense if the code base is large enough.

Comment: Comparing variables that all hold the same string constant is just as fast as comparing numbers

Comment: @Bergi hi, could you elaborate on this, it's just for my personal interest and professional growth? I can't grasp it. A number in IEEE is 4 bytes. The 'BANANA' is 12 bytes. Why comparing it to something is just as fast? Sorry, if it's a dumb question, but I don't have much fundamental education on computers. There is a question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836825/is-javascript-string-comparison-just-as-fast-as-number-comparison and based on its answers I think you meant that it's just as fast if we compare references. I.e. if we have a 'string-enum' and in other places use it

Comment: Not just another constant string

Comment: And so based on the answers to the question I referenced, I still think it's reasonable to use numbers, just to be safe. B/c the answers and comments there virtually say that it 'may be just as fast, but may be significantly slower'. So looks like using numbers makes sense

Comment: Yes, my point was string interning, the question you found goes into more details. Equality is fast (just a pointer comparison), inequality may need to traverse the string contents. However I'd argue that there will not be a measurable performance difference, and would rather prefer string values due to their better debuggability. Ymmv.