# In an ng-repeat I am comparing a string, is it faster to compare numbers?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this logic for some simple template logic in angular 1.5:

```
<p ng-if="myData.type !== 'customer'"></p>
```

Would it be be faster from a performance perspective to use numbers instead of a string comparison?? ie

```
<p ng-if="myData.type !== '0'"></p> ?
```

Comment: Your question might be equally valid when asking the same about Javascript (q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836825/is-javascript-string-comparison-just-as-fast-as-number-comparison)).  The answer would depend on the particular implementation of JS for a given browser.

Comment: Actually both cases shown are strings since you quoted `'0'`

Answer (score -1):

String comparisons are slightly slower, but barely. The difference will not be noticeable if the strings are shorter than 100 characters, and there are fewer than a million comparisons. Use strings if it is easier.

Comment: curious where you came up with 100 and 1 million? Seem like arbitrary round numbers without any citation