# Typescript switch case with logical and

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement

I am trying to write a switch statement but it doesn't seem to work how I want.

```
getExerciseDescription(exerciseId, intensity_level){

    alert(exerciseId + " " + intensity_level)

    switch (exerciseId && intensity_level) {
        case (1 && 1):
        this.header="Exercise 1 Level 1";
        this.instructions="Exercise 1 Level 1";
        break;
        case (1 && 2):
        this.header="Exercise 1 Level 2";
        this.instructions="Exercise 1 Level 2";
        break;  


        case (2 && 1):
        this.header="Exercise 2 Level 1";
        this.instructions="Exercise 2 Level 1";
        break;  
        case (2 && 2):
        this.header="Exercise 2 Level 2";
        this.instructions="Exercise 2 Level 2";
        break;

        default:
        this.header="Default";
        this.instructions="Default";
        break;
    }

    return new Popup(this.header, this.instructions);
}
```

The alerts gives 2 and 1 but the returned value is for (1 && 1). Why is it so? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You just can't use a `switch` like that. `(1 && 1) == (2 && 1) == 1` and `(1 && 2) == (2 && 2) == 2`, so you're doing the equivalent of:

```
    switch (exerciseId && intensity_level) {
        case (1): //...
        case (2): //...

        case (1): // same as above
        case (2): // same as above

        default:
        //...
   }
```

So of course the lower two cases will never execute. You're better of just using `if` and `else if` statements, or maybe nested switches if you want.

You could also do something like:

```
switch (exerciseId + " " + intensity_level) {
    case("1 1"): ...
    case("1 2"): ...
    case("2 1"): ...
    case("2 2"): ...
```

Comment: Just be warned, you take a performance hit comparing strings instead of numbers. Although with a string length of 3, it's probably not going to make any noticeable impact - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23837610/6806381

Answer (score 3):

That isn't how a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement will evaluate. For your scenario it will always evaluate to the 2nd integer in the logical and `&&`.

*(More information about [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators))*

> **Logical AND (&&)**
>
> `expr1 && expr2`
>
> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

You actually don't even need to use a switch, you can write it with a simple `if`

```
if (exerciseId <= 2 && intensity_level <= 2){
    this.header=`Exercise ${exerciseId} Level ${intensity_level}`;
    this.instructions=`Exercise ${exerciseId} Level ${intensity_level}`;
} else {
    this.header="Default";
    this.instructions="Default";
}
```

Comment: `"Exercise 1 Level 1"` for header and content was just an example, actually for each case there are different textual headers and instructions. So if else would be difficult.

Comment: Ok - you will most likely need to resort to multiple `if` statements then

Comment: I tried the above solution with string, it is lengthy but it worked. `this.switchString=exerciseId + " " + intensity_level` and then `switch (this.switchString){case ("1 1"): ..}`

Comment: String comparison is significantly slower than with numbers. I would advise against using strings just so you can use a `switch` statement

Comment: Okay sure. I will modify the code accordingly then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `switch(true)` then now you can use logical operator on `case`.

```
switch (true) 
{
        case (1 && 1):
        this.header="Exercise 1 Level 1";
        this.instructions="Exercise 1 Level 1";
        break;
        case (1 && 2):
        this.header="Exercise 1 Level 2";
        this.instructions="Exercise 1 Level 2";
        break;  

        case (2 && 1):
        this.header="Exercise 2 Level 1";
        this.instructions="Exercise 2 Level 1";
        break;  
        case (2 && 2):
        this.header="Exercise 2 Level 2";
        this.instructions="Exercise 2 Level 2";
        break;

        default:
        this.header="Default";
        this.instructions="Default";
        break;
    }
```

Comment: From version 5.3, TS does a better job at narrowing that `swich(true)` idiom: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-3-beta/#switch-true-narrowing

Answer (score 0):

The logical operators `&&`,  `||` and `!` always return `true` or `false` so the possible switch cases are only true and false. You should go with strings or numbers cases only.

Comment: Actually, the expression `2 && 2` evaluates to `2` and not a boolean